# Noise removal to create mask in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction

I need to create a mask to retrieve an object (foreground object) based on two related images.

Image 1:

[![enter image description here]

Image 2:

[![enter image description here]

The images contain a foreground object and a background with texture.
The two images are mostly the same except that in image2, the foreground object may have changed a little bit (it could have been rotated, translated or/and scaled).

Using OpenCV, I did the followings:

- perform image alignment (using `findTransformECC` with param `cv::MOTION_AFFINE`) to get transformation of foreground;
- do transformation to image1 (using `cv::warpAffine` with param `cv::INTER_LINEAR` + `cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP`) based on the transform matrix above;
- do absolute diff (`cv::absdiff` & `cv::threshold` with param `cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV`) between image2 and already transformed image1.

I think I am close to my goal but I still can not get clean mask of foreground object due to remaining noises on the background area.

[image]

What is the solution to remove all noise on the image_absdiff_invert.png (above) in order to create a clean mask of the foreground object ?

Comment: here is the image2.png <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="aAafY4K"><a href="//imgur.com/aAafY4K">View post on imgur.com</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: image2.png [link] (http://i.imgur.com/aAafY4K.jpg?1)

Comment: try to erode the mask once, follwed by a dilate (open operator) then use several close operators (dilate followed by erode)

Comment: Micka, thank you for the hints. i will try it tomorrow. i guess after opening and closing i can do findcountor to get foreground object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it.

Using morphological operations is often a bit tricky (trial and error) and gives me this result:

[image]

While using a median filter might be a good pre-processing (or maybe even enough for your contour extraction) and gives this result (this is just median blur from the input image, no morphological operations yet):

[image]

here's the test code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/maskNoise.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::Mat mask = input.clone();

    cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());

    cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    //cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    //cv::erode(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    //cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    //cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(mask, mask, cv::Mat());

    cv::Mat median;
    cv::medianBlur(input, median, 7);

    cv::Mat resizedIn;
    cv::Mat resizedMask;
    cv::Mat resizedMedian;
    cv::resize(mask, resizedMask, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    cv::resize(median, resizedMedian, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    cv::resize(input, resizedIn, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);

    cv::imshow("input", resizedIn);
    cv::imshow("mask", resizedMask);
    cv::imshow("median", resizedMedian);

    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/maskNoiseMorph.png", mask);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/maskNoiseMedian.png", median);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i can confirm the solution, thank you Micka-san. I just need to add morphological closing `cv::Mat closing;cv::Mat structuringElement = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(33, 33));
    cv::morphologyEx(median, closing, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, structuringElement);`